# ¿Cómo usar la funcion apply() para generar una nueva columna con la suma de dos datos de filas consecutivas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
ind = pd.date_range('01 / 01 / 2020', periods = 100, freq ='5min')
```

`Creating a dataframe with 4 columns using "ind" as the index for our dataframe`

```
dft = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 4),index = ind,columns =["a", "b", "c", "d"]) 
  

for i in dft.index:
    if i <(dft.index.max()- pd.Timedelta(minutes=5)):
        dft.loc[i + pd.Timedelta(minutes=5),"f"]=(dft.loc[i,"a"]+dft.loc[i + pd.Timedelta(minutes=5) ,"a"])
```

1. Este código funciona pero su rendimiento es muy lento, el código añade una quinta columna "f" al data frame con la suma de la dos filas consecutivas por ejemplo
   sumar fila 1 y 2 de la columana "a" y agregarla en la columna "f" en la fila 2 y así sucesivamente .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usa el método `.rolling()` de Pandas.
Aquí tu ejemplo:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ind = pd.date_range('01 / 01 / 2020', periods = 100, freq ='5min') 
dft = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 4),index = ind,columns =["a", "b", "c", "d"]) 


for i in dft.index:
    if i <(dft.index.max()- pd.Timedelta(minutes=5)):
        dft.loc[i + pd.Timedelta(minutes=5),"f"]=(dft.loc[i,"a"]+dft.loc[i + pd.Timedelta(minutes=5) ,"a"])

#Aplicamos rolling
dft["f"] = dft["a"].rolling(window=2).sum()
```

Hace lo mismo que tu función, basicamente en una ventana de tamaño *X* agrupa los *X* datos de la fila, y le aplica la operación que quieras, en tu caso la suma.

Es **muy usado en datos temporales** como los que tu tienes, por lo que pandas **permite que** en vez de usar un número de fila, también **puedas usar un espacio de tiempo**, por ejemplo `dft["a"].rolling("2s")` te cojerá todo lo que haya cada 2 segundos.

Puedes ver todo en la [documentación oficial de Pandas.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html)

Comment: Muchisimas gracias justo lo que ocupaba, funciona muy muy bien. Pregunta resulta.

Comment: De nada, un gusto ayudar. Como eres nuevo probablemente no lo sepas, pero la mejor manera de agradecer la ayuda en StackOverflow, es marcar la respuesta como "respuesta aceptada" el tick en forma de *"V"* esto no solo me recompensa a mí por haberte ayudado, si no que hará que la pregunta tome más relevancia y sea fácil de encontrar para las personas con la misma duda que tú en el futuro!